# sql one-to-one relation with null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with one-to-one relations like: people has one to one relation with status table

```
**people table**
ID  Name    Status
1   Mick    1
2   Rohit   null
3   Virat   1
4   Viru    null
5   Gilly   2
6   Shann   null
7   Mitch   3

**status table**
ID  Status 
1   started
2   not-started
3   pending
4   waiting
```

I need to get the people with status "null" and "started"(from ex: Mick, Rohit, Virat, Viru, Shann).

I tried with SQL query

```
select p.id, p.name
from people p
inner join status s on s.id = p.status
where (s.name IS NULL OR s.name = 'started')
```

this is giving only names which have a relation I mean "Mick, Virat" (skips nulls).

I don't know what I am missing here. thanks in advance

Comment: I doubt it's a one to one relationship. Each person might always have exactly one status, but each status might belong to many people. Also, if the the status field can be null, that would imply 0/1 to 1.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: I don't get this, do you want result Mick and Virat? Or do you want Mick, Rohit, Virat, Viru and Shann?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep `people` records where no `status` matches you need an `OUTER` join. In this case, a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, which is often shortened to just `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select p.id, p.name 
from people p 
left join status s on s.id = p.status
where coalesce(s.name, 'started') = 'started'
```